# Splitting a number and assigning to elements in a row in a numpy array

Tags: numpy, vectorization

How to place a list of numbers in to a 2D numpy array, where the second dimension of the array is equal to the number of digits of the largest number of that list? I also want the elements that don't belong to the original number to be zero in each row of the returning array.

---

**Example:**

From the list `a = range(0,1001)`, how to get the numpy array of the below form:

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,2],
 ...
 [0,9,9,8]
 [0,9,9,9],
 [1,0,0,0]]
```

Please note how the each number is placed in-place in a `np.zeros((1000,4))` array at the end of the each row.

**NB**: A pythonic, vectorized implementation is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) again!

```
def split_digits(a):
    N = int(np.log10(np.max(a))+1) # No. of digits
    r = 10**np.arange(N,-1,-1)  # 10-powered range array
    return (np.asarray(a)[:,None]%r[:-1])//r[1:]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [224]: a = range(0,1001)

In [225]: split_digits(a)
Out[225]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2],
       ..., 
       [0, 9, 9, 8],
       [0, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [229]: a = np.random.randint(0,1000000,(7))

In [230]: a
Out[230]: array([431921, 871855, 636144, 541186, 410562,  89356, 476258])

In [231]: split_digits(a)
Out[231]: 
array([[4, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1],
       [8, 7, 1, 8, 5, 5],
       [6, 3, 6, 1, 4, 4],
       [5, 4, 1, 1, 8, 6],
       [4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 2],
       [0, 8, 9, 3, 5, 6],
       [4, 7, 6, 2, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks again! This is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Another concept using `pandas` `str`

```
def pir(a):
    z = int(np.log10(np.max(a)))
    s = pd.Series(a.astype(str))
    zfilled = s.str.zfill(z + 1).sum()
    a_ = np.array(list(zfilled)).reshape(-1, z + 1)
    return a_.astype(int)
```

---

Using @Divakar's random array

```
a = np.random.randint(0,1000000,(7))

array([ 57190,  29950, 392317, 592062, 460333, 639794, 983647])

pir(a)

array([[0, 5, 7, 1, 9, 0],
       [0, 2, 9, 9, 5, 0],
       [3, 9, 2, 3, 1, 7],
       [5, 9, 2, 0, 6, 2],
       [4, 6, 0, 3, 3, 3],
       [6, 3, 9, 7, 9, 4],
       [9, 8, 3, 6, 4, 7]])
```

Comment: You might want to use `np.max()`, etc. as the input could be a list.